# use file for filter in Perl Net::LDAP

Tags: perl, ldap, netldap

when i'm doing an LDAPsearch manually on the commandline, i can do it so that the filter attribute can come off a file like this :

```
ldapsearch -v -h <host> -D "<DN>" -b "OU=myou,DC=mydc" -f myqueries.txt "(cn=%s)"
```

**myqueries.txt** contains entries such as :

```
name1
name2
nameN
```

now i'm trying to do the same thing in Perl using **Net::LDAP** and i couldn't find any option like that in the documentation.
do you know if it can do it ?

in the worst case, i know that i can probably create an array of records (containing queries) and make a loop with many ldapsearches on these names, it will work, but i'd prefer doing something easier with a net::ldap attribute if it is possible (less code)

e.g.

```
$data = $ldap->search(
     base   => $dn,
     scope  => 'one',
     pagesize  => '999',
     filter => '(cn=%s)',
     file => 'myqueries.txt',                # this option does not exist
     attrs  => [ qw( displayName cn ) ]
  );
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `ldapsearch -f` option is not implemented in Perl Net::LDAP, but you can still do the exact equivalent that is : performing a search operation for each line read from an input file :

```
open $handle, '<', $filepath;
chomp(@lines = <$handle>);
close $handle;

foreach $cn (@lines) {
  $data = $ldap->search(
     base   => $dn,
     scope  => 'one',
     pagesize  => '999',
     filter => "(cn=$cn)",
     attrs  => [ qw( displayName cn ) ]
  );
  ...
}
```

You can also avoid the foreach loop and still get the same results in one single query by concatenating the attribute values in a OR filter :

```
$filter = '(|(cn=' . join(')(cn=', @lines) . '))';
```

Comment: thanks, thats what i thought, will try both of the solutions and see what happens. as my input is quite huge i'm not sure it will accept the filter, i guess the loop solution is cleaner. will compare the speeds as well